# fluent validation not empty validator with clientside validation not working in mvc

Tags: validation, fluent

[This is my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq7cg.png)
[This is my validator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzDbu.png)

this is working in server side...but I need it in client side also.Plz tell me what changes i have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorate your view model as follows.

```
[FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(UserValidator))]

public class UserVM
{
  //properties
}
```

Also include jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js in your View.